# Webhooks Not working

Tags: webhooks, square-connect

I have enabled Webhooks in my portal but when any of the payments are accepted, I don't seem to receive any events. When I send an Test event thru the Dashboard that seems to work fine. Is there any reason why square is not sending any events when payments are accepted ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe to webhook events using the [Update Webhooks endpoint](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/index.html#put-webhooks) for each merchant before you will receive webhook notifications. They may also be sent after a short delay, so be sure to wait a bit before you try toubleshooting.

Comment: I had not registered for the events. It was not very clear on the dashboard about registration. After I read the documentation, there was a mention about it in the end.